# addEventListener not triggering

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I've tried different ways but the addEventListener is still not working.
Here's the Html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Drum Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <h1 id="title">Drum  Kit</h1>
  <div class="set">
    <button class="w drum">w</button>
    <button class="a drum">a</button>
    <button class="s drum">s</button>
    <button class="d drum">d</button>
  </div>


  <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and the Javascript code:

```
var n = document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length;
var i = 0;
while(i <n){

    document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        console.log("clicked");
        alert("clicked!");

  });
  i++;
}
```

Help me out with this.
ThankYou

Comment: Hello, link the script file correctly with correct path. refer this script tag and add your own path in the src `<script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>`

Comment: Your code works just fine. I removed the alert and added the classList to the console.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine if it's not working on your LOCAL then make sure your JS file is attached to your HTML file. Check console for error, if any error is there, pls tell me what is it? is it 404 or something else.

**As you implemented the script tag below, your HTML and JS file need to be in the same folder.**

```js
var n = document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length;
var i = 0;
while(i <n){

    document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        console.log("clicked");
        alert("clicked!");

  });
  i++;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Drum Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <h1 id="title">Drum  Kit</h1>
  <div class="set">
    <button class="w drum">w</button>
    <button class="a drum">a</button>
    <button class="s drum">s</button>
    <button class="d drum">d</button>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

You should try

```
client = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/");
```

or ready this [thread here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38604346/failed-to-construct-websocket-the-url-object-object-is-invalid)

Comment: and yes, both the files are in the same directory.

Comment: 1 Error handling response: Error: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The URL 'ws/ws' is invalid.          
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.preload.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.postload.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Comment: you JS code is ok, I think this would help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38604346/failed-to-construct-websocket-the-url-object-object-is-invalid

Comment: If this helped you, don't forget to mark it right answer and upvote.